# Accessing a constant doesn’t have any side effects

Tags: swift, constants

So I was reading [Swift Documentation on Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html#ID248). If you'll look at this topic,
after this code

```
let someAddress = Address()
someAddress.buildingNumber = "29"
someAddress.street = "Acacia Road"
john.residence?.address = someAddress
```

they have kinda made a statement that ***" it’s not easy to see that `someAddress` is never evaluated, because accessing a constant doesn’t have any side effects"*** and when you'll scroll down more, they have put the same block of code inside a function as below

```
func createAddress() -> Address {
    print("Function was called.")

    let someAddress = Address()
    someAddress.buildingNumber = "29"
    someAddress.street = "Acacia Road"

    return someAddress
}
john.residence?.address = createAddress()
```

My question is as follows:

Due to `Optional Binding` the function `createAddress()` was never called in second code and thus `someAddress` as never initialized.

So, does that mean that `someAddress` in **CODE #1** was also not initialised and just allocated some memory?

My thoughts??

`someAddress` in **Code #1** is JUST interpreted by the compiler i.e. Memory for a new instance of that class is allocated. The memory is not yet initialized. It will only be initialized once we will access it for the first time.

Actually, the statement **"`someAddress` is never evaluated, because accessing a constant doesn’t have any side effects"** brought me here.

Thoughts?

P.S What does *"accessing a constant doesn’t have any side effects"* mean in context to the current scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*So, does that mean that someAddress in CODE #1 was also not initialised and just allocated some memory?*

No. someAddress is explicitly initialized in the first line of example 1. What apple is telling you is that optionally chaining to assign that value to another value won't let you know if you succeeded or not; whereas the function contains a side effect (i.e. print("Function was called.")) so you'll be able to see that the assignment never happened.

Think of it this way - if you run the first code example, nothing prints and you have no idea whether the variable was assigned or not.

If you run the second example, nothing prints, which lets you know that the function was never run. This is what apple means when they say assigning a constant has no side effects.

Comment: Oh, so that's the "side effect" they were talking about. Thanks! That helped.

Comment: Yup. I agree, it's confusing - I had to read it twice myself.

Answer (score 2):

`createAddress()` is not called due to *optional chaining* in case `john.residence` is `nil`, there's no *optional binding* taking place in your code.

In case `john.residence` is `nil` in your first example, the already initialised `someAddress` isn't assigned to it due to optional chaining, but `someAddress` is initialized as soon as you call its initializer in the first line of your code, using `let someAddress = Address()`. The only difference the optional chaining makes in this case is that nothing holds a reference to `someAddress`, so it will be released from memory sooner than if it was assigned to the `residence` property of another object.

Comment: "so it will be released from memory sooner than if it was assigned to the residence property of another object." Is that what **"because accessing a constant doesn’t have any side effects"** trying to convey?

Comment: @Dennis no, that's completely unrelated to it.

Answer (score 1):

In code #1

`someAddress` is initialized and some memory is allocated but is not evaluated in the optional chaining line

In code #2

`someAddress` is not initialized because `createAddress` is not called at all

Both constants seem to be local anyway so the memory in code #1 is deallocated after exiting the local scope.

---

The statement *because accessing a constant doesn’t have any side effects* in this context means that you cannot see whether the right side is evaluated or not. That's why the `function` example is added.

Comment: " but is not *evaluated* **in the optional chaining line** " that's the confirmation I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: But can you also explain this line -> **because accessing a constant doesn’t have any side effects**

Comment: I'm sorry I won't be able to mark your answer as "answered" because @jglasse's answer cleared my doubt before your edited post. Thanks though :)